Do single detections influence the outcome of Bell tests?
Looking at the photon version of the Bell test, the setup is as follows. We have a photon source in the center. This source emits entangled photon pairs to two observers in opposite directions, Alice and Bob.
Each observer has a set of detectors that are positioned at a certain angle. The detectors can detect the spin of a photon. The spin state is either up or down. The detection of either spin state always results in an electric signal coming out of the detector and being logged in a device.
In a theoretical Bell test, both Alice and Bob will always detect a photon, when a photon pair is emitted. For real experiments, this is not always the case. There is a probability $> 0$ that Alice detects a photon with a certain spin state, and Bob does not detect a photon at all.
These single detection events occur quite frequently.
E.g.:

The directly measured arm efficiencies (each a ratio of observed coincidence and singles counts without any correction) measured in the $HV$-basis were $\eta_A = 73.77\% (\pm \ 0.07\%)$ in Alice’s arm and $\eta_B = 78.59\% (\pm
\ 0.08\%)$ in Bob’s.

from Bell violation with entangled photons.
How are those single detection events treated? Are they discarded?
Do they have an influence on the values in the Bell inequality?
If they are discarded, how can we be sure that the uncorrelated events are not hidden in those samples?

The photon version of the Bell test will have single detections since one of the photons may be blocked by the polarizer. But why do you say that there will be single detections too using electrons and Stern Gerlach measurements? Have some electrons disappeared while passing through the Stern Gerlach apparatus?

Bell-inspired tests have been done, afaik, only with light polarization. No massive particle spin pairs seem to have ever been Bell-tested.

@JánLalinský You probably missed entanglement experiments using particles with mass because the photon experiments are much more common (and easier to execute). Actually, there have been hundreds of such experiments. See for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.05949 (electron spins) https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4810 (ions) https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05586 (neutral atoms)

The Fair Sampling Assumption states that the events - where one detection occurs without its partner - occur randomly. This is often called the Detection Loophole. Let's suppose that the Fair Sampling Assumption is somehow invalid. This has already been addressed directly in a variety of experiments which consider ALL events, and do NOT discard single detections. See for example: arxiv.org/abs/1212.0533 arxiv.org/abs/1511.03190 (both teams led by Nobel prize winner Zeilinger) arxiv.org/pdf/1508.05949 These experiments are about 10 years old.

@DrChinese I did, thank you. Is there an experiment where spin projections are measured without light, e.g. with SG magnet and a particle detector?

The quick answer is that in most experiments you'd post-select on the "coincidences", that is, in practice, you simply ignore the cases where Alice and Bob don't both see an event. This reduces the overall statistics of the experiment depending on the amount of noise in apparatus and detectors, but doesn't otherwise change the expected results.
I should also note that this is pretty standard procedure in quantum optics experiments, it's not specific to Bell tests.
However, too much of this phenomenon can technically lead to a "loophole", meaning if you're post-selecting too much it might be possible to explain observations with a local hidden variable theory. This is the so-called detection loophole, which has also been mentioned in the comments. Loophole-free Bell tests have been performed experimentally to demonstrate this can be avoided, see for examples links in the comments above.

What do you think of the following statement: Checking if both Alice and Bob saw an event requires an exchange of information between the two.

@RafaelKeggenhoff sure
